# How to access intensity of all the pixels of Image in openCV C++

Tags: image, opencv

For accessing single point, I am using this line of code and it works

```
int intensity = gray_image.at<uchar>(Point(100, 100));
```

However when I use this code to access all the pixels in image, it gives memory error,

```
for (int i = 0; i < gray_image.rows;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gray_image.cols; j++) {
        intensity += gray_image.at<uchar>(Point(i, j));
    }
}
```

When I run above code, it does not give compile time error but gives memory exception. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: either `gray_image.at<uchar>(Point(j, i));` or `gray_image.at<uchar>(i, j);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just skip the use of Point and do the following.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gray_image.rows;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gray_image.cols; j++) {
        intensity += gray_image.at<uchar>(i, j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're requesting a pixel (j,i) that doesn't exist. This wouldn't have been an error in a square image (where the number of rows = number of columns), but you're using a rectangular image.

The Mat::at function has multiple prototypes, the two that you're concerned with are:

```
C++: template<typename T> T& Mat::at(int i, int j)
C++: template<typename T> T& Mat::at(Point pt)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) for Mat::at states that Point pt is defined as the Element position specified as Point(j,i), so you've effectively swapped your rows and columns.

The reason this happens is because the image is stored in a 1D array of pixels, and to get a pixel Point (r,c) is translated to p = r * image.cols + c;